# number too large

Tags: java

Hey , i hope i get help with this.

im a coder of a rsps (runescape private server)

and in this game you could like have items and weapons

and the max anmount of a item you can have is 2147000000

and i can change the amount of the max by changing this int

```
public int maxItemAmount = 2147000000;
```

and it works

but i want to make it like 3000000000

and i do this

```
public int maxItemAmount = 3000000000;
```

and when i compile i get this error

```
integrer number too large: 3000000000
```

please guys help me out if you can :)

Comment: Note that there's probably a good reason that the value is smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`: many, many places probably assume that all those values are passed around as signed 32 bit values (a.k.a. a Java `int`). Fixing those assumptions may prove to be non-trivial.

Comment: As a side note: `the max anmount of a item you can have is 2147000000` which player could handle than many items? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Integer has an upper bound of 2^31 (2147483648). If you want numbers longer than that, you can use a long or double.

Answer (score 3):

Integers are signed 32-bit values and thus can have a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup> = (note that one bit is used for the sign).

You need to change the type of `maxItemAmount` to long.

Answer (score 3):

you should go for 64 bit types ... i.e: `long` ...

do ...

```
public long maxItemAmount = 3000000000L;
```

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit signed integer has a range of -2<sup>32</sup> to 2<sup>32</sup>-1, or − 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.  If you want an integral value outside this range you need to use a 64-bit (long) variable.  On the other hand, how likely is it that anyone will have over 2 *billion* distinct items or weapons?  Perhaps, you want to rethink it and keep track of items and their quantities separately.  You might also want to consider that changing to use a long may have unexpected consequences if parts of the code assume that it's a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int` you should use `long`. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you can find more information about the precision of Java primitive data types.

Quoting from the link:

> long: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

Comment: @jmendeth I will follow your advice from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the max value of numbers with Integer.MAX_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE.

If a long is still not enough for your needs, you can check out the BigInteger class.

Answer (score 0):

As other people has sayed, you have to use another data type that support **big** numbers.
I recommend you using `long`. For example:

```
public long maxItemAmount = 3000000000L;
```

Notice the `L` at the end of the value. It tells the runtime that 3000000000 is a `long` value. Or use:

```
public long maxItemAmount = new Long("3000000000");
```

See more info [on this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

---

Also, someone commented using a `BigInteger`. It's like a `String`; don't have limit.
However, I recommend you to use it rarely. A `long` will probably suit your needs.

<sup>**EDIT:** Strictly speaking, `BigInteger`s and `String`s **have** limit (see comments).</sup>

Comment: strictly speaking, both String and BigInteger have upper limits; `2^31` characters and `2^31` bytes respectively.